# Android - Text View Change Font Size quickly

Tags: java, android, matrix, textview, zooming

I have an activity layout that have only one text view filling the whole screen. I want to display a matrix of characters in that text view. Assume the dimensions of such matrix are not lower than 800 x 600. I have made the text view scrollable, so that the user can move around both horizontally and vertically. I want to be able to reduce the font-size of the text, let's say every time the user tap the screen, so that if you touch it several times you will end seeing nothing but a little black square since the characters will be no longer visible due to their size.

The problem is that the text view is too slow updating the new font size every time a tap occurs. I want to create the illusion of a zooming out if you tap quickly. Is there any way to accomplish this faster?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to load data on webview if possible and u can easily zoom in and out in webview and loading data would also be simple